# Only one item get's displayed in x axis d3 - ordinal using tickvalues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a [pen](http://codepen.io/thomsebastin/pen/vGKBVL?editors=0010) here, that shows my problem. As you can see there is only one value in the x axis. I get all the values if I remove `tickvalues`, but that will cause problem with other data as there will be a huge set of data. I am using the `tickvalues` to limit the number of items to 20. This works for my other charts, but not for this chart. The scale is `ordinal` and in the console I am getting a `NaN` when calling xaxis. Which, I think is interfering with the `tickvalues`. If someone can look at the pen and provide any suggestions, it will be much appreciated. Here is the code parts. For full code, see the pen.

```
function plotVerticallyStacked(data) {

  checkLength(dataset);
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, WIDTH], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([HEIGHT, 0]);

  // Color range - add your favorites here
  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(_arr.map(function(d) {
      return d["state"];
    }));

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  appendResponsiveSvg();

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + "," + MARGINS.top + ")");

  var domain = ["sum(quantity)"];

  data.forEach(function(_data) {
    var y0 = 0;
    _data.groupedItem = [];
    _data.values.map(function(d, index) {
      _data.groupedItem.push(domain.map(function(name) {
        return {
          label: "quantity" + (index + 1),
          name: name,
          y0: y0,
          y1: y0 += +d[name]
        };
      })[0]);
      _data.total = _data.groupedItem[_data.groupedItem.length - 1].y1;
    });

  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.values[0]["sum(quantity)"];
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.total;
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + HEIGHT + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x((d.values[0])["sum(quantity)"]) + ",0)";
    });

  state.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.groupedItem;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.y1);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.label);
    });
}
plotVerticallyStacked(verticalStackedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/yg0rs4xc/17/

I find it easier to use fiddle :)

Insteadof tickValues I used tickFormat :

```
 .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      return d; 
    });
```

Let me know if that's ok :)

Comment: noticed theres not enough ticks, but the labels are there. Ill have another look

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it. And jsfiddle is fine by me. The problem I find with tickformat is, it display's some numbers where I want the state names  (`["AK","AL", "CA",..]` in this case). And the amount of ticks/items in x-axis should be limited to 20. Not more than that. I have `checklength()` function in my code to get `_arr` array with 20 items. But using them with `tickvalues` isn't just working out for me.